# How to execute python function at the given datetime

Tags: python-3.x, list, datetime, data-structures, python-multithreading

I have a list of dictionaries. Each item contains a `datetime` field in string format:

```
items = [{"Name":"Fooo","Time":"2 Jun, 7:20PM","Location":"LA"},
{"Name":"Yeam","Time":"27 Jun, 9:20PM","Location":"CA"},
{"Name":"Bar","Time":"12 Aug, 7:50PM","Location":"NY"},
{"Name":"Ahoy","Time":"20 Jul, 3:20AM","Location":"TX"}]

def myawesomefunc(item):
    # Do something awesome
    # and return the result
    pass
```

Now I want to invoke `myawesomefunc` for each `item` that satisfy:

`datetime.now() >= datetime.strptime(item['Time'], '%d %b, %I:%M%p')`

I can't sort `items` because it will changes continuously. Since the list may contain 30k+ items, iterating throw each item in `items` will be very time-consuming.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use some sort of data structure that make search and insertion more efficient, for example *Binary Search Tree ([BST](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-data-structure/))*.

Let us define some notation:

**`SubTree(N)`** : Function that return the set of descendent nodes of `N` including `N`.

**`Parent(N)`** : Function that return the parent of `N`.

**`X.left, X.right`** : The left and right children of a node `X`.

In case of *BST*, your search key will be the `timestamp` of each item. At equal intervals you will search for a node `X` with a key less or equal to `datetime.now()`, and you will execute `myawesomefunc` for each node in the set `S`:

```
S = {X} ⋃ SubTree(X.left) ⋃ (SubTree(X.right) if X.right <= datetime.now() else {})
```

Then you have to update your tree to exclude all processed node:

```
Parent(X).left = None if X.right <= datetime.now() else X.right
```

The insertion of new item is straight forward (normal insertion as any BST).

Now regarding execution of `myawesomefunc` you have two cases:

1. `myawesomefunc` is IO/bound operation: use [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example).
2. `myawesomefunc` is CPU/bound operation: use [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example).